# Passing variable as parameter to json_query function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, json

I am getting error:

> The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal

...while trying to pass variable as parameter to `JSON_QUERY` function. Please help me to resolve it.

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
DECLARE @cnt_total INT = 1;
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
declare @str  VARCHAR(200);

WHILE @cnt <= 10
BEGIN
    set @str = '$.Seasons[0].Products['+convert(varchar,@cnt)+'].ProductChannels';
    set @str = char(39) +@str+ char(39);
    PRINT @STR
    select @json = json_query(jfile,@STR) from Import.tstjson;
--MORE CODE     
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END
```

Sample data:

```json
{
  "Seasons": [
    {
      "Season": "12321231",
      "Products": [
        {
          "ProductId": "211",
          "ProductChannels": [
            {
              "ChannelId": 1,
              "WeekQuantities": []
            }
          ],
          "ccc": 3,
          "Tttt": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It is possible in SQL Server 2017.

From [JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql)

> In SQL Server 2017 and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a
>   variable as the value of path.

In SQL Server 2016 you have to build the query dynamically.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by creating dynamically

Answer (score 9):

I would guess that as it says 'string literal' you must pass `json_query` a string and not a variable, like in the [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) example

```
SELECT PersonID,FullName,
 JSON_QUERY(CustomFields,'$.OtherLanguages') AS Languages
FROM Application.People
```

So in your case, you'd probably need to `EXEC`.

**Disclaimer**: you'll need to ensure that your implemented code is not subject to SQL Injection.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500); 
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

WHILE @cnt <= 10
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT json_query(jfile, ''$.Seasons[0].Products['+convert(varchar(2),@cnt)+'].ProductChannels'') from Import.tstjson';
    EXEC @SQL;
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It's working now. One can take help of following code for similar problems

```
SET @SQLString = 'SELECT @json = json_query(jfile, ''$.Seasons[0].Products['+convert(varchar,@cnt)+'].ProductChannels'') from Import.tstjson';
    print @SQLString
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@json NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT';
    EXECUTE sp_executesql  
    @SQLString  
    ,@ParmDefinition  
    ,@json = @json1 OUTPUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            WHILE ( @start < @count)
            BEGIN
                declare @val varchar =@start;
                SET @json=JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$['+@val+'].value', @value);
                SET @start  = @start  + 1;
            END
```