# Passing Variable in json_value in sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, json

```
declare @id int
set @id = 1754
select 
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap."1754".value')) CorrespondanceNumber,
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap.***"'+cast(@id as varchar)+'"***.value')) Agency,
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap."1754".value')) Protocal
from actions_new a
left join action_data ad on ad.id_ref = a.id
where baid = 32 and displayrequestid < 100;
```

Its working with sql server 2017 but error showing in sql server 2016.

> Error : Msg 13610, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The argument 2 of the
>   "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal. Problem in
>   converting INT to vachar **"'+cast(@id as varchar)+'"**

Answer (score 0):

As answered for `JSON_QUERY` in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199593/passing-variable-as-parameter-to-json-query-function) the same is true for `JSON_VALUE` as well.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on `JSON_VALUE`

> In SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a
>   variable as the value of path.

Before `SQL Server 2017` you would have to build the query dynamically.

---

Examples

**Printing the query on sql server 2016**

```
declare @id int;
set @id = 1754;

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL ='
select 
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),''$.dataMap."1754".value'')) CorrespondanceNumber,
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),''$.dataMap.***"'+cast(@id as varchar(4))+'"***.value'')) Agency,
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),''$.dataMap."1754".value'')) Protocal
from actions_new a
left join action_data ad on ad.id_ref = a.id
where baid = 32 and displayrequestid < 100;';
PRINT (@SQL);
```

**Executing the query on sql server 2016**

```
declare @id int;
set @id = 1754;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Parameterdefinition nvarchar(20) ='@id int';
SET @SQL ='
select 
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),''$.dataMap."1754".value'')) CorrespondanceNumber,
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),''$.dataMap.***"+cast(@id as varchar(4))"***.value'')) Agency,
(JSON_VALUE(cast(ad.data_map as varchar(max)),''$.dataMap."1754".value'')) Protocal
from actions_new a
left join action_data ad on ad.id_ref = a.id
where baid = 32 and displayrequestid < 100;';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  
@SQL,@Parameterdefinition,@id;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9120fb2be472229196e072078bf1c55d)